# Can Squid cache parent proxy responses locally?

Tags: proxy, squid

I have a local / internal Squid proxy setup to make all HTTP requests through a parent HTTP proxy that requires authentication. What I would like to do is have the HTTP resources saved in the local Squid cache so that subsequent requests are served up from there rather than re-downloading from the parent.

My configuration looks something like this:

```
nonhierarchical_direct off

http_port 10101
acl port_10101 localport 10101
always_direct deny port_10101
never_direct allow port_10101

cache_peer parent.example.com parent 8080 0 no-query proxy-only login=user:pass connect-fail-limit=99999999 name=default_proxy
cache_peer_access default_proxy allow port_10101 
cache_peer_access default_proxy deny !port_10101

never_direct allow all
http_access allow all
```

I have tried removing `proxy-only` but that didn't do much.

This is for Squid 3.5.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to inspect the headers returned by the parent proxy. Normally, content that requires authentication is marked as uncacheable. Refer to [RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.1) section on "What Is Cacheable." If the parent is indicating that the response is uncacheable, then squid should be required to honor that, per RFC compliance.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that and it's a very good point. I will check out the headers and look into forcing the caching